# Image height not getting set to 100% of card

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
body,
html {
    background-color: red !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica light", Helvetica !important;
}

.thumbnailImage
{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}



  .mobileFlex {
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
   
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    
  }
  .ibm-card__content
  {
    padding:24px;
  
  }
  .card {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mainCard
  {
    padding:32px 24px 24px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .ibm-card__image
  {
    height: inherit;
    width: 38%;
  }
 
  #landing-page-heading {
    padding: 40px 14px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .cardTitle
  {
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .cardSubtitle
  {
    display: none;
  }
  .ucExplore
  {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#0F62FE;
  }
```

```html
<div id="landing-page-container" class="ibm-background-black-core">
            <div class="bg-overlay">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                    <h1 id="landing-page-heading"></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ibm-columns mainCard" data-items=".ibm-card" data-widget="setsameheight">
                    <div class="uc1 card" >
                        <div class="ibm-card mobileFlex ibm-no-border">
                            <div class="ibm-card__image">
                                <img id="use-case-img-1" class="thumbnailImage" src="https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/galform/cr/CR_TCDM_dump40_400_170000_12000_100_blue.gif" alt="card_1"></div>
                            <div class="ibm-card__content">
                                    <p id="use-case-title-1" class="cardTitle"></p>
                                    <p id="use-case-sub-title-1" class="cardSubtitle"></p>
                                <p class="ibm-ind-link">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadUseCasePage('0')" class="ibm-forward-link ibm-light"><span class="ucExplore">Explore</a></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

I am trying to make the image section of the card to have a 100% height with the card. Currently, there is a small gap below the image which needs to fill up completely to the card height.

Code below explains the details:

Have added height to inherit from parent but it still does not work

Added code snippet

Comment: Don't use jsfiddle - we need to see code in the question, preferably using a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)

Comment: remove the privacy popup from the fiddle, you have the image height hardcoded as well, use background image with background cover

Comment: js fiddle supports the external css classes I have used but the code snippet here does not @freefaller

Comment: @here, any reason why so many down votes, putting up reason would help me understand rather than only downvoting

Comment: I just ran your code snippet and it works as expected on my browser, no gap below the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `height` by `inherit` in `.ibm-card__image`  class

```
.ibm-card__image 
 {
  height: inherit; 
  width: 38%;
 }
```

Comment: added this on fiddle however the card image became smaller.

Comment: it can't be. Moreover, I was not the only one who gave such an answer. In which class are you making the change?

Comment: can you try it on my fiddle and run it.  Maybe the way my card css is handled is different. I tested this only this fiddle jsfiddle.net/xd5sfo1c/1

Comment: try adding a new rule to your CSS - `.ibm-card__image img {height: 100%;}`

Comment: This is already applied in the above fiddle. Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Add correctly which I wrote to you. Update the fiddle and link to it.

Comment: I have added the snippet here, Please have a check. Hope this helps to fix. If you notice there is a small space below image

Comment: This will help ---- `.ibm-card__image {height: inherit; width: 38%;}`

Comment: perfect, please add this to the answer so I can mark it as answer. Thank you. :) Please upvote too as my question is downvoted. I have made the changes to my question

Comment: Added to answer. You can check.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
.thumbnailImage{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Please change your height to 100%, don't make it static

Answer (score 0):

You can add snippets also to stackoverflow posts, your JsFiddle includes much more JS/CSS.

As per the answer, you have this CSS rule:

```
.thumbnailImage
{
  width:100%;
  height: 189px;
}
```

Just change it to:

```
.thumbnailImage
{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```